# Problem with devTools.send(Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride selenium 4

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, emulation, devtools

Selenium 4:

I have an error on this line of code :

```
    devTools.send(Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride(600, 1000, 50, true, Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));
```

the error:

The method
setDeviceMetricsOverride(Integer, Integer, Number, Boolean, Optional, Optional, Optional, Optional, Optional, Optional, Optional, Optional, Optional)
in the type Emulation is not applicable for the arguments
(int, int, int, boolean, Optional, Optional, Optional, Optional, Optional, Optional, Optional, Optional, Optional)

Comment: What is that _Number_ type data?

Comment: With jre 8 it works well, pb on java 11

Comment: Does this occur during the test run (i.e. after driver has launched a website) or when the java code is being parsed/compiled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v85.emulation.Emulation;


public class CDPFeatures {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
        devTools.createSession();
        
        Map deviceMetrics = new HashMap()
        {{
            put("width", 600);
            put("height", 1000);
            put("mobile", true);
            put("deviceScaleFactor", 50);
        }};
        driver.executeCdpCommand("Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride", deviceMetrics);
        
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        
        

    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced this issue but through some hit and trial method I was able to solve it. Hopefully it might help you. posting my code below:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v101.emulation.Emulation;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v101.emulation.model.DisplayFeature;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v101.emulation.model.ScreenOrientation;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v101.page.model.Viewport;

public class EmulationCDP {
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     
    
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","G:\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
    devTools.createSession();
    devTools.send(Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride(700, 1000, 50, true, Optional.<Number> empty(),
            Optional.<Integer> empty(), Optional.<Integer> empty(), Optional.<Integer> empty(), 
            Optional.<Integer> empty(), Optional.<Boolean> empty(), Optional.<ScreenOrientation> empty(), 
            Optional.<Viewport> empty(), Optional.<DisplayFeature> empty()));
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }
    }
```